# Improve sampling between R dataframes

Tags: r, data.table

I am trying to improve speed in a case where I need to use data from dataframes and sample from other dataframes.
First I need to draw the number of samples I want from df_obs. 
Then I need to determine a subset from where to sample based on which month I am in (the subset command).
Then I want to sample from the corresponding sample dataframe.
And finally put it all together in a new dataframe.

The code below Works, but it is far to slow, when I have to repeat this 1000 times. Is there an alternative method which uses apply functions better? Or perhaps some data.table function?

```
#Sample function to sample correct in case of only one value to sample from
resample <- function(x, ...) x[sample.int(length(x), ...)]

#Creating dummy data
no_pr_month <- sort(sample(67:120, 20))
df_obs <- data.frame(replicate(20,sample(0:5,1000,rep=TRUE)))
colnames(df_obs) <- no_pr_month
amount <- sample(50:50000,200)
month <- sample(no_pr_month,200, rep=TRUE)
df <- data.frame(month,amount)
df_sum <- data.frame(matrix(NA, ncol = 20, nrow=1000))

#The far too slow loop
for (k in 1:length(no_pr_month)){
  a <- df_obs[,k]
  df_sample <- subset(df, df$month == names(df_obs[k]))
  df_out <- sapply(a, function(x) sum(resample(df_sample$amount, x,replace = TRUE)))
  df_sum[,k] <- df_out
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Note: before creating your data, I inserted `set.seed(000)` for consistent results*

Even when using the `data.table` package, it's best to keep data organized in a "tidy" way: row-based.

So we'll start by changing your `df_obs` dataset to a long-form data.table.

```
library(data.table)

df_obs_long <- data.table(
  month     = as.integer(rep(names(df_obs), each = nrow(df_obs))),
  obs_count = unlist(df_obs)
)

df_obs_long
#        month obs_count
#     1:    69         4
#     2:    69         5
#     3:    69         1
#     4:    69         3
#     5:    69         0
#    ---                
# 19996:   116         4
# 19997:   116         1
# 19998:   116         2
# 19999:   116         3
# 20000:   116         5
```

Next we'll define a function that takes a vector of sample sizes and the number of the month to draw samples from.  The function will return a vector of sample sums for each of the sizes given.

Making `df` a `data.table` doesn't save much as far as written code, but can cut down runtime by a good amount.

```
setDT(df)


sample_and_sum_month <- function(sizes, month_number) {
  choices <- df[month == month_number, amount]
  vapply(
    sizes,
    FUN.VALUE = numeric(1),
    FUN = function(s) {
      sum(resample(choices, size = s, replace = TRUE))
    }
  )
}


sample_and_sum_month(1:3, 69)
# [1] 12729 55068 28605
```

Finally, we can just add the sums as a new column in `df_obs_long`.

```
df_obs_long[
  ,
  sample_sum := sample_and_sum_month(obs_count, .BY[["month"]]),
  by = "month"
]

df_obs_long
#        month obs_count sample_sum
#     1:    69         4      82662
#     2:    69         5     160761
#     3:    69         1       5743
#     4:    69         3     108783
#     5:    69         0          0
#    ---                           
# 19996:   116         4      56792
# 19997:   116         1      22570
# 19998:   116         2      35337
# 19999:   116         3      64734
# 20000:   116         5      69075
```

Comment: Thank you - this solution is much faster than the loop!